# Apache Tika Exception handling

Tags: scala, apache-spark, exception, try-catch, apache-tika

here is my code which is used to extract content and metadata, unfortunately this code runs into issue only when i pass a '.docx' document for parsing - while i'm figuring out how to fix that , can you please help with error/exception handling. No issue while parsing pdf

here is the code , the below try/catch are not helping . i would need the code to work irrespective of error and just log the error.

```
def extract (a: (String, PortableDataStream)) = {

val file : File = new File(a._1.drop(5))
val myparser : AutoDetectParser = new AutoDetectParser()
val stream : InputStream = new FileInputStream(file) 
val handler : WriteOutContentHandler = new WriteOutContentHandler(-1)
val metadata : Metadata = new Metadata()
val context : ParseContext = new ParseContext()
try {
myparser.parse(stream, handler, metadata, context)

stream.close
val headerrdd = handler.toString()
val meta = metadata.names()

metadata.add("txt", handler.toString())
val title = metadata.get("title")
}
catch {
case e: IOException => {
e.printstackTrace()
e.toString()
}
case e: TikaException => {
e.printstackTrace()
e.toString()
}
}
    //rest of the code to write output to file 
}
```

here is the error when i pass a .docx which is most likely cause of missing dependencies(trying to fix) but meanwhile, i would like the code to run by handling the errors
   `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:org/apache.poi.openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException
 at 
    org.apache.tika.parser.microsoft.ooxml.OOXMLParser.parse(OOXMLParser.java:82)
at
    org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parser(CompositeParser.java:281)
    org.apache.tika.parser.CompositeParser.parser(CompositeParser.java:281)
    org.apache.tika.parser.AutoDetectParser.parser(AutoDetectParser.java:281)`

Comment: Are u kidding us ? You didn't describe your problem at all. There is no error description of these you encountered. You didn't say what was the data ? Do you only have .docx ? Is the code working sometimes, or not at all ? Do you have other data formats ? We really can't help you if you don't clearly describe your data, what is the errors, what do you wanna do, etc...

Comment: @tricky  I have updated the thread . Any thoughts ?

Comment: Add all of the Apache Tika dependencies, not just some of them!